# SQL Server statement Where myfield content giving sub-string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a SQL Server statement to retrieve records Where myfield content giving sub-string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is to use LIKE:

```
SELECT
    MT.column_1,
    ....
FROM
    My_Table MT
WHERE
    some_column LIKE '%' + @search_string + '%'
```

Comment: This will work, but using the `%search%` pattern is a sure-fire way to skip any indices that might be present, thus resulting in a full table scan and thus horribly bad performance....

Comment: That's going to be the case in any solution, short of full text searches, where you're trying to find a string within a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CharIndex

```
Select * From YourTable
Where
CharIndex('yoursubstring', myfield) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try PatIndex.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE patindex('%string%', data ) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable where myfield like '%literalstring%'
```

or

```
select * from mytable where myfield like '%' + @stringvar + '%'
```

...not really clear on whether your substring is a literal or a variable